sys_poweroff not working after sleep in nrf52832_mdk
I am a beginner with NRF and zephyr and currently doing a small project on nrf52832_mdk on zephyr. I want to deep sleep the system (sys_poweroff) when nothing is happening. I followed the poweroff example and its working fine. I have attached a multimeter in paralell to measure current and I can see the current drop when system poweroff smootly.
In my actual project, when I run the sys_poweroff command in main thread after initialization, it gives the expected results. The system shuts down completely and current drops in micro amperes
int main(void){
printk("initializing the system \n");
int ret;
int errorCode = 0;
struct sensor_value regValue;

/**** Initialize LED****/
ret = led_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("could not Initialize LED \n");
}

/**** Initialize the SC7A20 Sensor ****/
ret = sc7a20_sensor_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("sensor Initialization failed \n");
    errorCode = ERROR_SC7A20_SENSOR;
}

ret = sc7a20_interrupt_register();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("Could not Register Interrupt for SC7A20 \n");
    errorCode = ERROR_SC7A20_INTERRUPT;
}

ret = button_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("could not Initialize Button \n");
    errorCode = ERROR_BUTTON_INIT;
}

ret = bluetooth_init(&bluetooth_callbacks, &remote_callbacks);
if (ret) {
    printk("bt_enable returned %d", ret);
    errorCode = ERROR_BLUETOOTH_INIT;
}

sc7a20_interrupt_controller_thread();

ret = battery_measure_enable(true);
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("Failed initialize battery measurement: %d\n", ret);
}
sys_poweroff();
}

However, If I run the sys_poweroff in another thread (or in the same main function after some sleep), it doesn't shut system appropriately. The system freezes there and current also remains same (only a little current drops). Here is a minimal code. The main objective is to poweroff the system from another thread. Its just a minimal example of situation where I get the same strange resuls
int main(void){
printk("initializing the system \n");
int ret;
int errorCode = 0;
struct sensor_value regValue;

/**** Initialize LED****/
ret = led_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("could not Initialize LED \n");
}

/**** Initialize the SC7A20 Sensor ****/
ret = sc7a20_sensor_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("sensor Initialization failed \n");
    errorCode = ERROR_SC7A20_SENSOR;
}

ret = sc7a20_interrupt_register();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("Could not Register Interrupt for SC7A20 \n");
    errorCode = ERROR_SC7A20_INTERRUPT;
}

ret = button_init();
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("could not Initialize Button \n");
    errorCode = ERROR_BUTTON_INIT;
}

ret = bluetooth_init(&bluetooth_callbacks, &remote_callbacks);
if (ret) {
    printk("bt_enable returned %d", ret);
    errorCode = ERROR_BLUETOOTH_INIT;
}

sc7a20_interrupt_controller_thread();

ret = battery_measure_enable(true);
if (ret != 0) {
    printk("Failed initialize battery measurement: %d\n", ret);
}
sys_poweroff();



if (errorCode == 0) {

    while (1) {
        battery_ble_notifier();
        k_msleep(40000);
        sys_poweroff();
    }
} else {
    led_error_sender(errorCode);
}

